# VirtualBox Ubuntu Stuck, Black Screen with White Spinner

Tags: boot, virtualbox, 20.04

I've been looking around on the internet, but haven't been able to find anything matching my intended description of what I am experiencing. But my Ubuntu ISO `ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64` is stuck on a black screen, with static white spinner.

[image: black screen]

This is generally occurring after the check disk

[image: Ubuntu Check Disk]

After Check Disk I get some "File Errors" (but it doesn't tell me which files are causing the problem)

[image: File Errors]

Below is my proposed config and runtime information

[image: Config]

[image: Run Time]

Comment: I've decided to try and give it another go and re-download the ISO again, not sure if the checkdisk is relative to primary DRIVE that is holding VDI file or whether it is relative to the ISO itself.

Comment: Your ISO is faulty - errors can be experienced (it tells you that). Did you verify your ISO ? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0   *It doesn't matter which files, most of your files as squashed into a HUGE squashfs, so ~98% of files are contained in that one file*

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with the Ubuntu 20 ISOs on VirtualBox version 6.1.18. I downloaded both `ubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso` and `ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso` and I've verified checksums. I get the exact same issue as you. Finally I just resorted to an old Ubuntu 19 ISO and upgraded to 20 within the OS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ISO is faulty.

Errors can be experienced (it tells you that).

Did you verify your ISO ? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

*It doesn't matter which files, most of your files as squashed into a HUGE squashfs, so ~98% of files are contained in that one file. Most of the other files are what boots your system, verifies & then opens the squashfs*

For more details, I'd suggest looking up https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1874662

If you filed a bug in your case, it's almost certain your report would be marked a duplicate of that (the other alternative would just be invalid due *squashfs* errors).

Comment: There are a small subset of cases that do result in this error (not being invalid ISO), you'll find those mentioned in the listed bug report.  You can switch to term & view your *syslog* output to confirm issue.

Comment: I've just downloaded a brand new ISO and same issue happens

Comment: Did the checksum match? (ie. check mentioned in how to verify ubuntu ISO).  If you switched to term, were squashfs errors evident?  (a `dmesg | grep squashfs` should only find version/coder notice, no later errors).  See comments in provided message too, for issues in VMs and host settings

Comment: I’m not sure how to check the checksum on a windows PC

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided (ie. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) , it has a "*For Windows*" section ....  There are other tools that don't assume WSL/windows 10 too, tools that provide checksum files natively and not via WSL